# FireMonkey ComboBox assigning Selected. Text from query

Tags: delphi, text, combobox, firemonkey, assign

I need to allow my users to view a previously selected item from a ComboBox.  A query provides the previous choice to the ComboBox.

I was hoping Live Bindings would get me through it, but it is so slow, I can't use it.

I am able to complete a similar action using a ComboEditBox, but can't seem to sort out what needs to be done with the ComboBox.

For the ComboEditBox, the following code works fine:

```
ComboInspector1.Text := FDQueryGetInspectionInspector_1.Text;
```

However, the following code does not work for the ComboBox:

```
ComboStationLocated.Selected.Text := FDQueryGetInspectionStation_Found.Text;
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you just trying to select an entry in a combobox given a string? or are you trying to overwrite the text of the selected index?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to select an item based on some text, so below will select an item in the combobox if it already exists from the text of YourObject (whatever this may be)

```
ComboStationLocated.ItemIndex:=ComboStationLocated.Items.IndexOf(YourObject.Text);
```

If this is not what your are trying to do I will edit my answer.